# How Do I Get the Remaining Transaction Refund Balance with Authorize.Net?

Tags: e-commerce, authorize.net

With Authorize.Net, I see no way to use the [Transaction Details (TD) API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/transaction_details/) in order to find the remaining transaction refund balance, such as someone who buys two products at once on a given transaction, gets refunded on one product, and then the next day comes back and wants to get refunded on the second product. Unless I store those prices somewhere, I have no way to know how much to refund. And this gets more complicated when exchange rates are used, where the price fluctuates a little. The only way to refund properly on the second product is to get the remaining refund balance and refund that balance.

What's the trick to get the remaining balance that I can still refund out of the transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to get that information through their API. The merchant account provider does not provide this information nor does Authnet keep track of this information themselves. Basically you need to keep track of open balances, available refunds, etc on your end.

Comment: Confirmed. I'm going to have to store SKU1 and 2 USD balances in my database at time of Euro conversion to USD so that I can refund them individually back with the proper amount.